# "The connection was reset" error caused by specific .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost

I've recently upgrade my local development environment to Apache 2.4.33 and PHP 7.1.7

No such issue using previous versions of Apache and PHP.

I have a css file which is called directly from the browser `/css/styles.min.css` It was working fine until I updated the file contents and saved it but now in both Firefox and Chrome I get the equivalent of "The connection was reset" errors.

File permissions and ownership are fine. No issues there.

I can fix it temporarily. I've narrowed it down to a single line in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.1[0-9]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js) $1.$2
```

The line is in use, but doesn't match the file seeing the error. Commenting out that line resolves the issue in both Firefox and Chrome.

There must be an error log somewhere which will suggest a solution, but I can't find it in error_log or access_log

Really odd one. Hopefully somebody can suggest something I can try?

**Update**

If I only leave the minimum content in the .htaccess file, the problem no longer happens, even though the line is active.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's `mod_deflate` related

I have no idea why removing a single line of the .htaccess file would temporarily resolve the issue, but the update below solves this issue with the css file and another issue with another url parsed by php which was giving the same error. So I'm now able to put .htaccess redirects back in how they were previously.

I replaced:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript text/x-component
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/richtext text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
</IfModule>
```

With an updated version which will function given no module, apache >= 2.4 or < 2.4

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
  <IfModule filter_module.c>
      <IfModule version.c>
          <IfVersion >= 2.4>
              FilterDeclare  COMPRESS
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#^text/(html|css|plain|xml|x-component)#i"
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#^application/(javascript|json|xml|xhtml+xml|rss+xml|atom+xml|vnd.ms-fontobject|x-font-ttf)#i"
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#^image/(svg+xml|x-icon)#i"
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'font/opentype'"
              FilterChain    COMPRESS
              FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
          </IfVersion>
          <IfVersion < 2.4>
              FilterDeclare COMPRESS
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
              FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
              FilterChain COMPRESS
              FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
          </IfVersion>
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule !version.c>
          FilterDeclare COMPRESS
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
          FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
          FilterChain COMPRESS
          FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
      </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```